# Why is the start of a line "^" and the end of line "$"?

Tags: regex, line-endings, mnemonics, end-of-line, start-of-line

I never remember whether `^` matches the beginning of the line and `$` matches the end of it or the other way around. A good mnemonic would be that the `$` sign is always before the price, therefore it matches the beginning of a line - unfortunately it's the other way around.

So is there any reason why these two characters were chosen for the beginning and end of line?

Comment: Personally, I reckon [they] just chose two characters that hadn't been assigned yet.

Comment: Dont know about the reason. But they never confuses me. My thinking is different. Every time I see `^`, `$` I interpret it as start and end. E.G. See the $ of the document. If you ever use `vi` you'll notice `0`, `$` means start and end.

Comment: $ represents the newline character(s) in asm language, I think this is related

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One mnemonic: In an auction, bidders start by raising `^` their paddles. The price `$` is established at the end.

Answer (score 1):

I memorize `^` as: It points to where it came from, i.e. the previous line, so it should stand at the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

The $ used to mean the end of the line in very early editors, like ed.
The ^ was probably chosen because it was about the last unused character on keyboards at the time :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is probably due to the relative positions of these two characters on a QWERTY keyboard:
'^' in first position (start of line) and '$' after (end of line).

EDIT: My bad, this is only valid on a french keyboard ([AZERTY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AZERTY)). It provides a mnemonic for AZERTY user but not an explanation.

Comment: And it would be backwards because?

Comment: Seems you need to remember the word *backword* with this rule too.

Comment: @lc.: What is your comment supposed to ask? It is not backwards.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth The fact that $ (4) comes before ^ (6), at least on a US layout.

Comment: @lc. ah, ok. On my german layout ^ is to the left of 1 and $ is on 4 :-)

Answer (score 0):

`\A` and `\Z` do roughly the same, except they are subtly different to `^`/`$` with respect to new line characters.

So if you remember that and also remember that `^` looks most similar to `A` and `$` is most simliar to `Z` that might be enough of a mnemonic.